# Using Images To Populate UITableView

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm very new to iOS programming, and am trying to figure out something that is probably trivial. I'm trying to fetch Json data from Flickr, specifically just images, and use this data to populate pictures on a UITableView. This is my attempt:

```
- (void)jsonParsing
{
    //-- Make URL request with server
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tagmode=any&format=json&tags=QUERY"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //-- Get request and response though URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    //-- JSON Parsing
    self.flickrArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Result = %@",self.flickrArray);

    for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in self.flickrArray)
    {
        NSString *string = dic[@"media"];
        if (string)
        {
            NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            dic[@"media"] = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in url response");
        }
    }

}





- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.flickrArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSData *imageData = [self.flickrArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return cell;
}
```

The only thing happening in the NSLog is : Result = (null). I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: It's helpful to pass in an `NSError` pointer to both the `-sendSyncrhonousRequest` and  `+JSONObjectWithData`, then inspect it after those calls to see if there was an error. In your cases you're passing 'nil' so you don't know that anything went wrong.

Comment: It is also useful to test return values for nil.

Comment: Is *responseData nil too?